# Image in sidebar pushes down content in main area

Tags: html, css

I have an issue, where the logo image on the left sidebar actually pushes down the content in the div to the right of it. Can anyone explain why that might be happening? The H1 should be at the top of the page, but it only sits there when I remove the logo image.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/GHKxW/1/)

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.wrapper {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.wrapper > div {
    display:table-cell;
}
.wrapper .left {
    width:200px;
    background-color:#34495E
}
table {
    width:100%;
    background-color: pink;
}
td {
    background-color: fff;
}
tr {
    height: 60px;
}
th {
    text-align: left
}
#btn_pri {
    background-color: 60A0DF;
    color: white;
}
#btn_sec {
    background-color: #e74c3c;
    color:white;
}
.navigation {
}
.navigation li {
}
.navigation li span {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(http://www.otlayi.com/web_images/content/free-doc-type-sprite-icons.jpg) no-repeat left center;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.navigation li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.navigation li a:hover {
    background-color: #495C6D;
}
.navigation li a.active {
    background-color: #495C6D
}
#rss span {
    background-position: -52px -68px;
}
#photos span {
    background-position: -90px -66px;
}
#links span {
    background-position: -45px 0;
}
h1 {
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.logo {
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.btn {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    height: 34px;
    border-radius:3px;
    border: 0px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:12px;
}
#btn_pri {
    background-color: #60A0DF;
    color: white;
}
#btn_sec {
    background-color: #e74c3c;
    color:white;
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are using `table-cell;` so you need to use `vertical-align: top;` as well.

```
.wrapper > div {
    display:table-cell; 
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GHKxW/2/)</kbd>

Also, I feel your CSS is horrible, sorry to be blunt here, but using generalized element selector like

```
tr {
    /* Something */
}

td {
    /* Something */
}
```

will cause you problems in the long run, you should always be specific, assign a `class` to your `table` element and use the selector like

```
table.class_name tr {
    /* Something */
}
```

which looks tidy.

Comment: Ah that works, thank you. May I ask your opinion on using the table-cell for this layout?

Comment: @Jimmy I think you can accomplish the same with the `float` as well :) `table-cell` is something which is used when a user wants the sidebar to be stretched along with the main element and so on